# gradle init throws CycleDetectedException when converting a simple maven project

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Running `gradle init` on a very basic project - only 2 test dependencies (`junit` and `assertj-core`) causes `CycleDetectedException`. Full error below.

Any idea why a simple Maven Java project cannot be converted to Gradle?

```
alik@ap:~/DevP/lean$ gradle --stacktrace init
:wrapper UP-TO-DATE
:init
Maven to Gradle conversion is an incubating feature.
:init FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':init'.
> Could not convert Maven POM /home/alik/DevP/lean/pom.xml to a Gradle build.
   > Unable to create Maven project model using POM /home/alik/DevP/lean/pom.xml.
      > Cycle detected in component graph in the system: 

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':init'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.internal.maven.MavenConversionException: Could not convert Maven POM /home/alik/DevP/lean/pom.xml to a Gradle build.
    at org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.internal.PomProjectInitDescriptor.generate(PomProjectInitDescriptor.groovy:44)
    at org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.internal.TemplateOperation$generate.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.buildinit.tasks.InitBuild.setupProjectLayout(InitBuild.groovy:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.internal.maven.MavenConversionException: Unable to create Maven project model using POM /home/alik/DevP/lean/pom.xml.
    at org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.internal.maven.MavenProjectsCreator.create(MavenProjectsCreator.java:51)
    at org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.internal.maven.MavenProjectsCreator$create.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.internal.PomProjectInitDescriptor.generate(PomProjectInitDescriptor.groovy:41)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainerException: Cycle detected in component graph in the system: 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.initialize(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:624)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.construct(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:281)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:172)
    at org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.internal.maven.MavenProjectsCreator.createNow(MavenProjectsCreator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.internal.maven.MavenProjectsCreator.create(MavenProjectsCreator.java:49)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.CycleDetectedInComponentGraphException: Cyclic requirement detected
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultCompositionResolver.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultCompositionResolver.java:65)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.DefaultComponentRepository.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultComponentRepository.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultComponentRegistry.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultComponentRegistry.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:514)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.discoverComponents(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:969)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.discoverComponents(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:941)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.initialize(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:560)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.dag.CycleDetectedException: Edge between 'Vertex{label='org.apache.maven.plugin.MavenPluginManager:default'}' and 'Vertex{label='org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolver:default'}' introduces to cycle in the graph org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolver:default --> org.apache.maven.plugin.MavenPluginManager:default --> org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolver:default
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.dag.DAG.addEdge(DAG.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.dag.DAG.addEdge(DAG.java:123)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.composition.DefaultCompositionResolver.addComponentDescriptor(DefaultCompositionResolver.java:60)
    ... 79 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.342 secs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems that the Ubuntu's 16.04 apt gradle version is 2.10 and it has a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=810817).

I downloaded latest (v4.6) from [here](https://gradle.org/releases/) and everything worked fine.

* Sharing my knowledge ([It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))